# How to subset AAs FROM AAString object?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, substring, subset

I have a AAString set like below how can I subset regions from seq column.

```
df <- AAStringSet(c("MEKIVLLLA", "MEKIVLDIA"))
```

Input:

```
df:

AAStringSet object of length 2:
     width  seq        names  
       9    MEKIVLLLA  A1
       9    MEKIVLDIA  A2
```

Output:

```
AAStringSet object of length 2:
     width  seq        names  
       6    MKLLLA  A1
       6    MKLDIA  A2
```

I used below code but it is not working:

```
positions <- c(1,3,6,7,8,9)
end_positions <- c(1,3,6,7,8,9)
subseq(df, start = positions, end = end_positions))
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the `AAStringSet{c(`...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a `base` approach,

```
seq1 = 'MEKIVLLLA'
seq2 = 'MEKIVLDIA'

paste(unlist(strsplit(seq2, split = ''))[c(1,3,6:9)], collapse='')
[1] "MKLDIA"
paste(unlist(strsplit(seq1, split = ''))[c(1,3,6:9)], collapse='')
[1] "MKLLLA"
```

And then delving into the complexities...

```
seq1_AA = Biostrings::AAString(x = seq1, start = 1)
seq1_AA
9-letter AAString object
seq: MEKIVLLLA

seq1_AA[c(1,3, 6:9)]
6-letter AAString object
seq: MKLLLA

Biostrings::subseq(seq1_AA[c(1,3,6:9)])
6-letter AAString object
seq: MKLLLA
```

And I've found my way to your hell. `?XVector::subseq` is the avenue I'm looking at, without much success yet, in order to apply to AAStringSet, rather than by row... Which leads us to `IRanges::solveUserSEW`, confusion mounts, head explodes, and one assumes this stew of mystery must be wrapped for mere mortals.

Someone who actually knows `Biostrings` will come along. The furthest my understanding has come is

```
Biostrings::AAStringSet(c(as.character(seq1_AA[c(1,3,6:9)]),as.character(seq2_AA[c(1,3,6:9)])))
AAStringSet object of length 2:
    width seq
[1]     6 MKLLLA
[2]     6 MKLDIA
```

that seems unsatisfying as one wants to bypass the `c(...` and apply the indexing to all `seq`, imagining a df$seq that doesn't exist in a sea of pointers. `?IRanges::narrow` has `threebands()`, that has a left, middle, right that seems very much like `c(1,3,6:9)`, the kind of narrowing proposed, and you'd hope `subseq` manages all that as against my seemingly mechanical reductions of seq within `c(`. Sigh.

My explorations are likely unnecessary here, but when you have many members in your `AAStringSet`, all seeking the same reduction/simplification

```
str_6 = list()
for (i in 1:length(AAseq_12)) {
str_6[[i]] <- unlist(AAseq_12[[i]])[c(1,3,6:9)]
}
str_6_set = Biostrings::AAStringSet(str_6)
str_6_set
AAStringSet object of length 2:
    width seq
[1]     6 MKLLLA
[2]     6 MKLDIA
```

One still holds out hope for `subseq`, but navigating the `subscript out of bounds` errors...